# Why/when can't $ be used instead of parentheses in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have the impression that I can use `$ ...` to represent `(...)` as long as there is nothing to the right of `...`.

However, when I try to re-write  the following

```
dist' x y = abs  <$> ( (-) <$> x <*> y)
```

as

```
dist x y = abs  <$> $ (-) <$> x <*> y
```

I get an error:

```
 error: …
    parse error on input ‘$’
    Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
  |
Compilation failed.
```

I can live with writing the parenthesis, but I am just curious. Why (or when) does the `$` not work in replacing `()`.

(This is with GHC 8.2.2)

Comment: You can't use two operators in a row.

Comment: Rahul Manne’s answer already explained why, but just to add some alternatives: you could keep `($)` and `(<$>)` using an operator section `(abs <$>) $ (-) <$> x <*> y`, but that’s a bit silly—I sometimes use the named `fmap` instead of the `(<$>)` operator in this situation: `fmap abs $ (-) <$> x <*> y`. You could also remove a level of nesting with `liftA2` instead of the `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` operators: `abs <$> liftA2 (-) x y`; or if you’re going to be using this lifted subtraction pattern often, define `(.-) = liftA2 (-); infixl 6 .-` and write `abs <$> x .- y`.

Comment: BTW, `dist` is not a good name for this function. A distance should always be a scalar.

Comment: `$` is in fact not really Haskell syntax, it is an operator defined in the prelude.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$` is an operator, same as `<$>`. The problem is that you have two binary operators following one another.

`$` works the way it does specifically due to its declaration (`infixr 0`), where it takes the lowest priority. (See: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-)

See https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#fixity for more information.

Answer (score 11):

Although it is in practice indeed used primarily for this purpose, the `$` operator is not in any fundamental way syntactically linked to parenthisation – it's just another infix operator (i.e. 2-argument function written in the middle between arguments), like `+` or `*` or `<$>`. What the operator does is take a function on its left side and a value that the function should be applied to on the right. So, for instance `sqrt (1 - x^2)` can be written `sqrt $ 1 - x^2`, because `sqrt` is just a function and instead of flat out applying the function to its argument you can also use the `$` to do the same thing, benefiting from the low `infixr 0 $`.

The function may also be a composition or partial application of other stuff, as in

```
(sum . map (^2)) (0 : xs)   ≡   sum . map (^2) $ 0 : xs
```

But `abs <$> ((-) <$> x <*> y)` is not of this form: it is *already* an infix expression.

We can however exploit the fact that Haskell allows partial application also of infix operators, because that gives you a *simple function* form. You need an *operator section*:

```
abs <$> ((-) <$> x <*> y)   ≡   (abs <$>) ((-) <$> x <*> y)
```

and this is now of simple function-application form, so you can make it

```
(abs <$>) $ (-) <$> x <*> y
```

Of course that somewhat defeats the point, because the operator section has introduced another pair of parentheses, so in this case the original way of writing the expression probably remains the best. Fortunately though, `<$>` also comes in a plain-function form, namely

```
fmap abs $ (-) <$> x <*> y
```

Another option would be to rewrite the `<*>` subexpression: `f <$> a <*> b` is the same as [`liftA2 f a b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2), which as a plain function binds tighter than the infix `<$>` anyway. So

```
abs <$> ((-) <$> x <*> y)   ≡   abs <$> liftA2 (-) x y
```

Or alternatively, remove the outer `fmap` entirely: if you first define

```
numDist :: Num a => a -> a -> a
numDist a b = abs $ a - b
```

then you can just write

```
dist x y = numDist <$> x <*> y
```

...or

```
dist = liftA2 numDist
```